# Heart (♥) and Broken Heart () symbols in Music Player

Tags: 8.0, music, icons

I found Heart (♥) and Broken Heart () symbols in Music Hub of Windows Phone. Is there any relevance to these symbols in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Are you asking if they exist on WP8?

Comment: It's already exists in WP8 and what's its use in WP8?

Answer (score 2):

These are 'love' and 'hate' indicators. When playing a song you can tap on the heart icon (neutral by default) to switch between love, hate, and neutral.

These are used to provide you suggestions for other music in the Store and other related libraries. Possibly for Smart DJ too (though I don't have a reference for that).

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/How-to/wp7/music/music-and-video-faq # "How do I rate a song on my phone"

Comment: I'm asking it's relevance in WP8.

Comment: It's the same as in WP7, as above. Except that for WP7 the love/hate info would also sync to the Zune player, whereas for WP8 there is no Zune sync.

Comment: That means useless in WP8 right?